# Cannot index document in elasticsearch while performing string operation

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have to index documents in elasticsearch which are stored in a file, and i am indexing the documents while i am performing string operation on it. (i have to partition the line and use the splits separately)

```
rec = open(file)

for line in rec:

    val_1 = line.partition(' ')[0].strip()
    val_2 = line.partition(' ')[1].strip()
    #print   str(val_1) + " " + str(val_2)
    es.index(index="test", doc_type="trial", id = val_1, body = val2)
```

I can print this line, but cannot index it for some reason. It throws out following error.

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 69, in >_wrapped return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client__init__.py", line >261, in index _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params,body=body)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 307, in >perform_request status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)

This error is the same if i perform those operations inside the loop

```
es.index(index = "test", doc_type= "trial", id = line.partition(' ')[0].strip(), body = line.partition(' ')[2].strip())
```

Am i sending the parameters in a wrong way? Where should i start looking to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: Its a silly mistake really. 
What i wrote is this

```
es.index(index="test", doc_type="trial", id = val_1, body = val2)
```

What i missed was to format the body properly.
It should be

```
es.index(index="test", doc_type="trial", id = val_1, body = {"name": val2 } )
```